# How to reduce a number of sequential find(1) invocations?

Tags: bash, shell, find

I have the feeling a refactoring is required on this shell script:

```
find -name *.java >> filelist.txt && find -name *.ftl >> filelist.txt && find -name *.xhtml >> filelist.txt && find -name *.html >> filelist.txt && find -name *.jrxml >> filelist.txt && find -name *.xml >> filelist.txt
```

It searches for certain file types recursively.
How would you minimize this code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine expressions with the `-o` flag, so it becomes:

```
find -name '*.java' -o -name '*.xhtml' -o -name '*.jrxml'  >> filelist.txt
```

And so on for your other file types. 
Note: quote the wildcard, `'*.java'` instead of just `*.java` , otherwise you 
   risk `*.java` expand to .java files in your current directory.

Answer (score 4):

If the order of the filenames in `filelist.txt` doesn't matter, you can use the `-o` operator (which means "or") like this:

```
find -name "*.java" -o -name "*.ftl" ... >> filelist.txt
```

Note that this will change the order of the files in the `filelist.txt` as with your command, all `*.java` files would be first, then all `*.ftl` files, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Try this command:

```
for a in *.java *.xhtml *.jrxml; do find -name ${a} >> ; done
```

Comment: That doesn't reduce the number of calls to `find`; it just makes the code to do so more compact. Also, you can't have a dangling `>>` operator like you show.